# How to use pipenv on mac?

Tags: python, macos, zsh, pipenv, pipenv-install

When install it by pip(`pip install pipenv`), on zsh shell can't find the command `pipenv`.

If install it by `brew`: `brew install pipenv`, then run `pipenv shell`, got error

```
Loading .env environment variables...
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 429, in shell
    do_shell(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2387, in do_shell
    shell.fork_compat(*fork_args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/shells.py", line 106, in fork_compat
    c = pexpect.spawn(self.cmd, ["-i"], dimensions=(dims.lines, dims.columns))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 205, in __init__
    self._spawn(command, args, preexec_fn, dimensions)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 276, in _spawn
    raise ExceptionPexpect('The command was not found or was not ' +
pipenv.vendor.pexpect.exceptions.ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: /use/bin/zsh.
```

There isn't a path naming `/use/bin/zsh`. Why it's unstable?

The shell path is

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

Comment: Are you sure it says /use, with an e, not /usr, with an r? /usr/bin/zsh would be a somewhat reasonable place to look for zsh (but not on a Mac, apparently), but /use/bin/zsh is just bonkers.

Comment: @TurePålsson Yes, I added the full error message.

Comment: @Miantian : So there is obviously a typo in some script. Search for where `/use/bin/` is written, and fix this using your text editior.

Comment: @user1934428 When I ran `ls /use/bin/`, got `"/use/bin/": No such file or directory (os error 2)`. There isn't this directory.

Comment: Of course. What did you expect???

Comment: Consider using `pyenv` instead of managing `python` and `pip` manually

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're asking two questions, really. I'll answer each in a separate section:

## How to fix that error

> ```
> Loading .env environment variables...
> ...
> The command was not found or was not executable: /use/bin/zsh.
> ```

Looks like [in your `.env` file](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#automatic-loading-of-env), you have `PIPENV_SHELL=/use/bin/zsh`. That's incorrect. Instead,

- it should be

  ```bash
  PIPENV_SHELL=/bin/zsh
  ```
- or simply

  ```bash
  PIPENV_SHELL=zsh
  ```
- or you can **just remove it.** Then `pipenv shell` will automatically use the same shell as from which you invoked it.

## How to properly install `pipenv` on macOS

The right way to install `pipenv` on macOS is convoluted, but it's the only way to avoid running into trouble whenever you upgrade Python:

1. Undo what you've done so far:

   ```bash
   % pip uninstall pipenv
   % brew uninstall pipenv
   ```
2. Add to your `.zshrc` file:

   ```bash
   eval "$( brew shellenv )"

   # Set your preferred python version.
   # If you just want the latest release, you don't need to 
   # specify anything more than the major version number.
   export PYENV_VERSION=3

   # Tell pyenv where to keep your python installations.
   export PYENV_ROOT=~/.pyenv

   # Tell pipx where to install executables.
   # pipx is like brew, but for python.
   export PIPX_BIN_DIR=~/.local/bin

   # -U eliminates duplicates.
   export -U PATH path         
   path=( 
       $PIPX_BIN_DIR
       $PYENV_ROOT/{bin,shims} 
       $path
   )

   # Installs/updates pipenv and all of its dependencies.
   pybake() {
     # If any commands fail, exit the function.
     setopt LOCAL_OPTIONS ERR_RETURN

     install-or-upgrade() {
       print -n ${${$( command -v $1 ):+upgrade}:-install} $1
     }

     {
       brew ${=$( install-or-upgrade pyenv )}
       pyenv install --skip-existing $PYENV_VERSION
       pip install --upgrade pip

       # --user installs to ~/.local/bin
       pip install --upgrade --user pipx

       pipx ${=$( install-or-upgrade pipenv )}

     } always {
       unfunction install-or-upgrade
     }
   }
   ```
3. Run:

   ```bash
   % exec zsh  # Restart your shell.
   % pybake
   ```
4. Add to your `.zshrc` file:

   ```bash
   eval "$( pyenv init - )"
   eval "$( pip completion --zsh )"
   eval "$( register-python-argcomplete pipx )"
   ```
5. Run `exec zsh` again or open a new terminal tab.

### Updating `pipenv`

After following the steps above, to update `pipenv`, all you need to do is run:

````
```shell
% pybake && exec zsh
```
````

Comment: Your final line draws an error: Error: No such option: --completion Did you mean --python? Open issue here but it looks like they have no plans to add completion back: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4991
If you remove eval "$( pipenv --completion )" you then begin to receive "command not found: complete". It looks like this entire procedure may need an update.

Comment: OK, that sucks; it used to work. Thanks for letting me know; I’ll remove that line.

Comment: That script doesn't work for me. While running pybake I get: Successfully installed argcomplete-3.0.5 click-8.1.3 pipx-1.2.0 userpath-1.8.0
pybake:17: command not found: pipx. And the second time exec zsh is run it gives: .zshrc:53: command not found: register-python-argcomplete.

Comment: @WebSnake Sorry, I'm not able to reproduce that. Feel free to open a new question for this.

Comment: I have ran it now and have a same issue as @WebSnake. I've run `export PATH=$(python3 -m site --user-base)/bin:$PATH` after and rerunning the script worked.

Answer (score -1):

**This works 100% for MacOS**

How to setup virtual env using pipenv

`brew install pipenv` # if you have brew installed

`pip3 install pipenv` # if you don't have brew installed

Open the ~/.bash_profile using a text editor by the following command

`vi ~/.bash_profile` # i used vi text editor

And write the following statements at the end of .bash_profile

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then use pipenv easily without issues by the following commands:

```
pipenv shell # To activate pipenv
exit # deactivate and quit
pipenv install <libraryName> # install a library
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!