# Option "completion" not found when installing pipenv on Mac

Tags: python, macos, zsh, pipenv

I am following the solution in this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67733566/how-to-use-pipenv-on-mac) to "properly" install `pipenv` on Mac.

At the last step, when running the command `exec zsh`, I receive this error message:

```
(eval):46: command not found: complete
Usage: pipenv [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'pipenv -h' for help.

Error: No such option: --completion Did you mean --python?
```

What does this error mean? Does it mean `pipenv` has failed to installed? Because I am able to fire up a virtual environment with `pipenv shell`

Answer (score 1):

In your .zshrc:

Try replacing the line `eval "$( pipenv --completion )"` with `eval "$(_PIPENV_COMPLETE=zsh_source pipenv)"`

Source: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv#shell-completion

Answer (score 0):

These lines are **no** longer needed to be added within .zshrc for for magic shells:

`eval "$( pipenv --completion )"`
`eval "$(_PIPENV_COMPLETE=zsh_source pipenv)"`

The error is due to the completion flag being removed from Pipenv since the shell already has completion by using the tab button.

*"The last maintainer had dropped the --completion flag and we don't intend to add it back. [They] also recently fixed a different bug around completion being broken."*

**Source**: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4991